# exception after setting "Result column binding"

Tags: entity-framework

I have a SQL server database which have two entities and 4 stored procedures for each entity ( Select, Insert, Update, Delete) and I'm using Entity framework to do data access work in my application. (the application is just for training purpose)

I mapped Insert procedure to an entity and it worked but after that I changed the "Result column binding" to "Id" -identity column-
this caused this exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.

after searching for a short while I didn't find the reason for it,
then I figured it's what I changed "Result column binding" so I removed it.

Just want to know what is the cause of this exception. what went wrong.